# Advanced Installer VSTO Add-in Deployment to Entire Machine not working

Tags: vsto, office-addins, ms-project, advanced-installer, comaddin

I'm using Advanced Installer to try to create an installation package (single EXE setup file) for an MS Project VSTO add-in. I need the installation Type to be ***Per Machine*** but when I chose this option and run the setup.exe file, the Add-in will not load for any of the user's on the target machine. The only way I can get it to load is if I change the installation type to ***Per User***, which I don't want.

I'm fairly certain the problem is related to the registry, because the setup.exe is not adding the proper registry keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to load the add-in, even though I have it set up to do so:

[image: registry settings]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are other things that needs to be done except windows registry keys. For example, you need to [specify whether you want to support per-user or per-computer installations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#to-specify-whether-you-want-to-support-per-user-or-per-computer-installations).

The [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#to-specify-whether-you-want-to-support-per-user-or-per-computer-installations) article describes all the necessary steps for creating per-use and per-machine Office add-in installers. Make sure that you did everything in your installation package.